# Why <img> element doesn't consider as DOM node in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I was writing a program to get all `<img>` tag from DOM using node interface. I notice that there is no nodeType for `<img>` element tags. Is it possible using DOM tree only we get the `<img>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `.nodeName`, not `.nodeType`. the nodeName of an img tag is `'IMG'`.